# Selecting Entry and exit record for each entry in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join, union

The following is a sample from the table I have

```
F_ID     R_ID       DATE    Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
 12      158      20161008    01      99     99
 12      158      20161012    01      01     99
 12      158      20161019    01      02     10
 12      158      20161022    99      01     10
 12      160      20161006    01      99     01
 12      160      20161011    99      01     99
 12      160      20161017    99      01     10
 17      167      20161013    99      01     01
 17      167      20161016    99      02     99
 17      167      20161020    02      01     10
 17      174      20161010    99      01     01
 17      174      20161012    01      02     11
 17      174      20161017    99      99     10
```

I want to select such that I get the following result

```
F_ID   R_ID    DATE     Col_A   Col_B   Col_C
12     158    20161008    01      01     99     -  Entry record
12     158    20161022    99      01     10     -  Exit Record
12     160    20161006    01      99     01     -  Entry record
12     160    20161017    99      01     10     -  Exit Record
17     167    20161013    99      01     01     -  Entry record
17     167    20161020    02      01     10     -  Exit Record
17     174    20161010    99      01     01     -  Entry record
17     174    20161017    99      99     10     -  Exit Record

For each  F_ID, R_ID:
When Col_A or Col_B = '01' and Col_C <>'10' - **It is an entry record**
When Col_C = '10' - **It is an exit record**
```

Logic here is

```
1. Select the earliest entry record 
   **and** 
2. Select the latest exit record for each F_ID, R_ID
```

I'm thinking of using union like below...

```
Select * from tbl1 T
where 
T.Col_C = '10' and 
T.DATE = (select max(T2.DATE) from tbl1 T2
                                 where
                                 T2.Col_C = '10' and
                                 T2.R_ID = T.R_ID
                                 T2.F_ID = T.F_ID
          ) 

union

Select * from tbl1 K
where
(K.Col_A = '01' or K.Col_B = '01') and 
K.Col_C <> '10' and
K.DATE = (select min(K2.DATE) from tbl1 K2 where 
                      (K2.Col_A = '01' or K2.Col_B = '01') and 
                       K2.Col_C <> '10' and
                       K2.R_ID = K.R_ID
                       K2.F_ID = K.F_ID
          )
```

But using union like I did on the same table with self joins is returning me a garbage data.

Comment: What happens when `Col_A <>  '01'` and `Col_B <>  '01'` and  `Col_C <> '10'` ? this is nor Entry, nor Exit record, so what is this? You just skip records like this?

Comment: What does "garbage data" mean exactly? The query looks okay in my opinion. An `ORDER BY` clause would help of course. And `UNION` doesn't make much sense as there can be no duplicates you'd have to eliminate; use `UNION ALL` instead.

Comment: Col_A <> '01' and Col_B <> '01' and Col_C <> '10' -- This condition can still be count as an entry record

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand, you need this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT T1.*,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID  ,   R_ID order by DATE)   rn, 'Entry record' as rec FROM (
        SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE (Col_A = '01' or Col_B = '01') and Col_C <> '10'
    ) T1
    union all
    SELECT T2.*,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID  ,   R_ID order by DATE DESC)   rn , 'Exit record' as rec FROM (
        SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE  Col_C = '10'
    ) T2
) t3
where rn = 1
```

**edit**

More simplified version (thanks to @ThorstenKettner)

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT your_table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID, R_ID order by DATE) as rn, 'Entry record' as rec FROM your_table WHERE (Col_A = '01' or Col_B = '01') and Col_C <> '10'
    union all
    SELECT your_table.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID, R_ID order by DATE DESC) as rn, 'Exit record' as rec FROM your_table WHERE Col_C = '10'
) t3
where rn = 1
ORDER BY F_ID, R_ID, DATE
```

Comment: This can be simplified by invoking `ROW_NUMBER` and `WHERE` at the same time instead of nesting this. And then: an `ORDER BY` clause would get the data in the desired order.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - How both `WHERE` clauses may implement at same time? I don't get it.

Comment: `SELECT T1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY F_ID, R_ID order by DATE) as rn, 'Entry record' as rec FROM your_table WHERE (Col_A = '01' or Col_B = '01') and Col_C <> '10'`

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - oh, thank you, I understand what you mean, you're right.

Comment: Thanks @OtoShavadze  This gets me closer but I have unequal Entry and exit records. For a few F_ID and R_ID's I only have entry but no exit record and vice versa. How to filter this to get records for only those which have a valid entry and an exit record?